# Store newly self-built installation, with old binary-installed installation

Tags: software-installation

I just built the most recent version of `pdftk` by `make -f Makefile.Debian`, and I got an executable `pdftk` in my local directory. (http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/)

I have an older version of `pdftk` under `/usr/bin/`, installed from binary and the software center of my Ubuntu.

Is it a good practice just to replace the executable?

- How about the old manpage?
- Will the OS have the information of the new executable, when I query for that by `dpkg -l`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would encourage you to *not* replace any executables that are part of a package that was installed using APT or `dpkg`. It's better to keep this file in the directory `/usr/local/bin`, IMO, given it's custom software that you've built yourself.

Also I'd take a look at that "Makefile", `Makefile.Debian` to see if it includes a `make install` target. That target, will often already be setup to install the binaries that were built into a directory such as `/usr/local`, typically.

**NOTE:** The targeting of this directory is often configurable when you run the `./configure` step, which "customizes" the targeted install directories.

#### Other questions

> How about the old manpage?

Using the install target will often times install man pages and other build artifacts into corresponding directories under `/usr/local` too.

> Will the OS have the information of the new executable, when I query for that by `dpkg -l`?

No, installing files manually would cause the packages to be negated, and so and further management of the package using the package management software will no longer be able to track these modified files.

Comment: I found that in the makefile, `make install` just does `/usr/bin/install pdftk /usr/local/bin`. The command `pdftk` points to the new `/usr/local/bin/pdftk` rather the old `/usr/bin/pdftk`. Is it because '/usr/local/bin` is searched before `/usr/bin`? The manpage and the `dpkg -l pdftk` are still not changed, i.e. still about the old executable.

Comment: @Tim - yeah your `$PATH` env. var. has `/usr/local/bin` occurring before `/usr/bin` so when it encounters `pdftk` in `/usr/local/bin` it uses that first.

Comment: @Tim - `dpkg -l pdftk` doesn't actively search the filesystem so it's oblivious to the changes your `make install` made. This is kind of one of the dirty secrets of package management. It's a very loose coupling b/w what it views is installed on the system vs. what's actually installed on the HDD.